# Should I worry about redirecting index.php to root or not?

Tags: seo, redirects, google-search, url

I've read in a forum two users saying that Google identifies index.php and the site's root as a single page, that redirecting index.php to root is not something we should worry about, but as they had no sources, I'm in doubt if it is true.

Is it true?
I wonder if leaving things as they are (Without redirecting) is bad for SEO.

Answer (score 1):

I have client who earns pagerank 2 with the same issue as yours. I redirected index.php as default home page into (even) folder `/id/`. However, I include canonical as an exact information for google to see ...

> *"where my home address is actually"*

That means that what google needs is our final decision in related to this. As long as we include `meta canonical` and other site authority, This would never be a significant problem.

See also: [moz](https://moz.com/learn/seo/redirection)

Comment: How to add canonical?

Comment: you can set inside tag `<head></head>` as meta tag and also many methods. such as: google webmaster (if you need this), A Record, TXT Record, and Upload a file in root of web

Answer (score 1):

> ...Google identifies index.php and the site's root as a single page

These two things can totally be different.

> ...that redirecting index.php to root is not something we should worry about.

I'd personally worry about it because:

1. index.php is not a friendly URL especially if it has a query string attached to it.
2. not having a friendly URL could entice hackers in trying to manipulate your site by playing around with parameters and such.

At least if I redirect index.php to root or any other friendly URL page, then I'm effectively masking out ideas for the hacker.

> I wonder if leaving things as they are (Without redirecting) is bad for SEO.

You can get a better rank if your URL contains keywords that are part of your webpage (which is why I'd suggest friendly URLs). Also, if accessing http://example.com/index.php and http://example.com result in the exact same page, then redirecting http://example.com/index.php to http://example.com will make your rankings better because you just indicated to google and search engines which of the two copies of content you'd rather display to the user.